# Jqueryui Autocomplete was working but now it's not

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I tried to use a Jqueryui autocomplete. It was working perfectly. but now its not. here is the code..

the input field:

```
   <input class="form-control mandatory" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Enter your name please" type="text" onkeypress="return stop(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;">
```

and this is the code for autocomplete

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
  var name = document.getElementById('name');
            $(name).autocomplete({
                    minLength : 2,
                    source: "getemaillist.php"
                });
            });
```

I checked in firebug, but there is neither GET nor POST request.

then I tried adding keyup="getdata(this.value)" to input tag and in that function getting data by using $.post and assigning returned result as source to autocomplete. I'm getting data in proper json format. but still I can't see autocomplete in action.

I just see a get request to css/images/ui-bg_highlight-soft_100_eeeeee_1x100.png file which is I think an autocomplete background image.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: do you type more that 2 characters?

Comment: Yes, i did, infact, I can see a get request to autocomplete image, as mentioned above.

Comment: The source you are giving should be an array value not the php page.

Comment: It can be a php page, only that the page should return array encoded in json, by the way , the above code is working fine now..

Answer (score 0):

You can use directly without using `onkeypress` event, autocomplete works automatically in onkeypress.

Use this:

```
$("#name").autocomplete({
                    minLength : 2,
                    source: [
          "ActionScript",
          "AppleScript",
          "Asp",
          "BASIC",
          "C",
          "C++",
          "Clojure",
          "COBOL",
          "ColdFusion",
          "Erlang",
          "Fortran",
          "Groovy",
          "Haskell",
          "Java",
          "JavaScript",
          "Lisp",
          "Perl",
          "PHP",
          "Python",
          "Ruby",
          "Scala",
          "Scheme"
            ]
                });
            });
```

and I have a doubt in your source data `source: "getemaillist.php"`
Please make sure that assigned datas is in correct format.

For reference use this [Link](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)

Hope this may helpful.

Comment: thank you for your help. but it is working fine now, and I'm still using the code I have given above. thanks for your help, though.

Comment: Welcome YiiFighter :)